# Data Validation before inserting in database on button click WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created one MVVM application in which i am adding customer info(customer id , customer name ) in one database table by using textboxes. there are two modes of this app first is insert mode and another is edit mode. In insert mode i can add new informations in database and in edit mode i can edit existing values, all i need to do is i have to avoid duplicate customer id when i add in insert mode and popup error and in edit mode same i want to edit existing cust name and also edit cust id to new uniq one and in case of invalid case pop up error. Name can be multiple but id should be unique in table this is primary req.
so far i have created application and inserting data in database but i am not getting any idea how to validate this data on save button click. Any help highly appreciated.

here are application codes. 
**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
   <TabControl >
        <TabItem Header="Insert" >
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="63*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="118*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="326*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Custmore ID :" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <Label Content="Custmore Name :" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="custIdTxt" Text="{Binding Path=CustId}"  Height="23" Grid.Column="2"   Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,4"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" x:Name="custNameTxt"  Text="{Binding Path=CustName}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,4" />
                <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Path=InsertCommand}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,240,0"/>

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Edit" Margin="-2,-2,-18,-1" >
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Custmore ID :" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Label Content="Custmore Name :" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="custId1Txt" Text="{Binding Path=CustId}"  Height="23" Grid.Column="1"  Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" x:Name="custName1Txt" Text="{Binding Path=CustName}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Path=InsertCommand}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,240,0" />

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <ListView Name="ListViewCustomerDetails" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,150,0,0"    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridDataTable }"  >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="grdTest" >
                <GridViewColumn Header="CUSTOMER ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CUSTOMER_ID}"   Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="CUSTOMER NAME" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CUSTOMER_NAME}"  Width="100" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        vm.GetData();
    }
}
```

And here is viewmodel class
**MainViewModel.cs**

```
 class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel 
 {
    private string custName;
    private int custId;


    public string CustName 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.custName;
        }

        set
        {
            this.custName = value;
            OnProprtyChanged("CustName");
        }
    }
    public int CustId
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.custId;
        }
        set
        {
            this.custId = value;
            OnProprtyChanged("CustId");
        }
    }

    private DataTable _dataTable;
    public DataTable GridDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataTable;
        }
        set
        {
            _dataTable = value;
            OnProprtyChanged("GridDataTable");
        }
    }

    private ICommand _insertCommand;
    public ICommand InsertCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_insertCommand == null)
                _insertCommand = new RelayCommand(param => InsertItem());
            return _insertCommand;
        }
    }

    private void InsertItem()
    {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add(Constants.CONST_CUST_ID, this.CustId);
        ht.Add(Constants.CONST_CUST_NAME, this.CustName);

        Model model = new Model();
        int res=model.InsertRecord(ht);
        if (res > 0)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(res + " row(s) Inserted.");
            GetData();
        }
    }

    public void ResetGridDataTable()
    {
        this.GridDataTable = null;
    }
    public void GetData()
    {
        ResetGridDataTable();
        Model model = new Model();
        DataTable dt=model.GetAllData();
        this.GridDataTable = dt;
    }
}
```

Model class
**Model.cs**

```
class Model
{
    public int InsertRecord(Hashtable ht)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=XE;User ID=system;Password=practice;Unicode=True");
        int result=0;
        try
        {
            int custId = Int32.Parse(ht[Constants.CONST_CUST_ID].ToString());
            string custName = ht[Constants.CONST_CUST_NAME].ToString();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('" + custId + "','" + custName + "')";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public  DataTable  GetAllData()
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=XE;User ID=system;Password=practice;Unicode=True");
        DataTable dt =new DataTable();
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```